# How to fill color based on certain conditions in a column of pandas dataframe while writing it to excel?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe :

```
id  TEST    VALID   EFFECT_SIZE
1   913     853          0.44
2   559     641          -0.6
3   545     402          1.05
4   528     479          0.36
5   464     437          0.2
```

[image]

I want to fill the color in effect size column as given in the image attached.
The condition is if effect_size greater then 2 then column should be red ..if greater than equal to 0.6 then column should be yellow else white.

i am able to do that in dataframe using the below code :

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    
    color = 'red' if val>1.20 else 'yellow' if val>0.6 else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df2.style.applymap(color_negative_red,subset=['effect_size'])
```

but when i am trying to write it in excel..the colour disappers.Anyone can help me how can i fill the colour in excel sheet based on the above conditions?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to resign to df2 when you use `applymap`

```
df = [{'id': 1, "TEST": 913, "VALID": 853, "EFFECT_SIZE": 0.44},
{'id': 2, "TEST": 559, "VALID": 641, "EFFECT_SIZE": -0.6},
{'id': 3, "TEST": 545, "VALID": 402, "EFFECT_SIZE": 1.05},
{'id': 4, "TEST": 528, "VALID": 479, "EFFECT_SIZE": 0.36},
{'id': 5, "TEST": 464, "VALID": 437, "EFFECT_SIZE": 0.2},]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(df)
def color_negative_red(val):
   color = 'red' if val > 1.20 else 'yellow' if val > 0.6 else 'white'
   return 'background-color: %s' % color


writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"/tmp/test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
df2= df2.style.applymap(color_negative_red, subset=['EFFECT_SIZE'])
df2.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```